# Probability two withdrawn balls are the same color

Tags: probability

Suppose we have $n$ white and $m$ black balls in a urn. First, randomly withdraw two balls, what is the probability (Call it $P_1$) that they are the same color? Now, suppose a ball is randomly withdrawn and then replaced before second one is drawn, what is the probability (Call it $P_2$) that withdrawn balls are same color? Finally prove that $P_2 > P_1$.

#### try

For the first situation sample space size is ${m + n \choose 2 }$. Now, in how many ways can we withdraw balls the same color? If both are white, then can do this in ${n \choose 2}$ ways and if both are black can do in ${m \choose 2}$. Thus

$$ P_1 = \frac{ {m \choose 2 } + {n \choose 2} }{ {m+n \choose 2 } } $$

Now, for second situation, two cases. If the first ball drawn is white, then the probability this happens is ${n \choose 1 } / {m+n \choose 1 } = \frac{n}{m+n} $ . For the seecond ball we want it to be white so this can be done in ${n-1 \choose 1 } / {m+n-1 \choose 1 } = \frac{n-1}{m+n-1} $ so for this case we have $\frac{n(n-1) }{(m+n)(m+n-1)}$. Similarly if the first ball drawn is black we obtain probability $ \frac{m(m-1) }{(m+n)(m+n-1)}$.Thus,

$$ P_2 = \frac{ m(m-1)  + n(n-1) }{(m+n)(m+n-1) } $$

But, Im stuck in trying to prove $P_2 > P_1$. Is my approach correct?

Comment: In the second situation , the probability of the second ball being white is the same as that for the first ball because of the replacement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When working without replacement, we can either select $2$ white balls with probability

$$\frac{n}{n+m}\cdot\frac{n-1}{n+m-1}$$

or $2$ black balls with probability

$$\frac{m}{n+m}\cdot\frac{m-1}{n+m-1}$$

giving $$P_1=\frac{n}{n+m}\cdot\frac{n-1}{n+m-1}+\frac{m}{n+m}\cdot\frac{m-1}{n+m-1}$$

which is equivalent to what you have done.

When working with replacement, the probability does not change after the first draw giving

$$P_2=\frac{n}{n+m}\cdot\frac{n}{n+m}+\frac{m}{n+m}\cdot\frac{m}{n+m}$$

It suffices to show that for two positive integers $$\frac{x}{x+y}\gt\frac{x-1}{x+y-1}$$

Can you go from here?

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track for $P_1$ , *drawing without replacement*.

Next, notice that $\dbinom{x}{2}=\dfrac{x\,(x-1)}{2!}$, and so

$$P_1 ~{=\dfrac{\binom m2 +\binom n2}{\binom{m+n}2} \\ = \dfrac{m(m-1)+n(n-1)}{(n+m)(n+m-1)}}$$

---

However, $P_2$ needs to be rethought.  (Notice that you actually evaluated the first situation .)

Rememer, it is *drawing with replacement*.   That means you *won't* have one less ball on the subsequent draw (as it's been *replaced*).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are drawing the balls with replacement in part 2, you do not need to modify the number of balls being chosen from. The number of ways to choose 1 ball out of n balls is ${n}\choose{1}$. The number of possibilities of the same thing twice is ${{n}\choose{1}}^2$